# css grid calculate fraction from variable

Tags: css, grid, css-grid, css-variables

I have a div with `display: grid;`

I am using css properties / variables to have a dynamic website, which I then update via javascript.

I managed to achieve this using scss

```
grid-template-columns: var(--user-column-width) $days-shown + unquote('fr');
```

The question is, is it possible to have something like

```
grid-template-columns: var(--user-column-width) var(--days-shown)fr;
```

I did not yet succeed in combining the variable and fractions together. So if possible, how can it be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `calc(1fr * var(--days-shown))` to achieve this, as long as `--days-show` is unitless.